# Compare two files content in Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, text, apache-spark

I want to compare every word in my file with a list of external words, please look at this example:

my data file is :

```
surprise heard thump opened door small seedy man clasping package wrapped.

upgrading system found review spring 2008 issue moody audio mortgage backed.

omg left gotta wrap review order asap . understand hand delivered dali lama

speak hands wear earplugs lives . listen maintain link long .

buffered lightning thousand volts cables burned revivification place .

cables cables finally able hear auditory gem long rumored music .
...
```

and external words file is :

```
thump,1
man,-1
small,-1
surprise,-1
system,1
wrap,1
left,1
lives,-1
place,-1
lightning,-1
long,1
...
```

when it compare these words, if some words in every document same as external words then sum their values , and finally we have one score for every document
and expected output is :

```
 -2 ; surprise heard thump opened door small seedy man clasping package wrapped.

 1 ; upgrading system found review spring 2008 issue moody audio mortgage backed.

 2 ; omg left gotta wrap review order asap . understand hand delivered dali lama

 0 ; speak hands wear earplugs lives . listen maintain link long .

 -2 ; buffered lightning thousand volts cables burned revivification place .

 1 ; cables cables finally able hear auditory gem long rumored music .
 ...
```

i've tried :

```
object test {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("prep").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val searchList = sc.textFile("data/words.txt")

val sentilex = searchList.map({ (line) =>
  val Array(a,b) = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
  (a,b.toInt)
}).collect().toVector

val lex=sentilex.map(a=>a._1)
val lab=sentilex.map(b=>b._2)
val sample1 = sc.textFile("data/data.txt")
val sample2 = sample1.map(line=>line.split(" "))
val sample3 = sample2.map(elem => if (lex.contains(elem)) ("1") else elem)
sample3.foreach(println)
 }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i think that the best way to do what you want is using broadcast values in order to send the sentilex and later use a map function to calculate the sum. In code would be something like this:

```scala
object test {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("prep").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val searchList = sc.textFile("data/words.txt")

val sentilex = sc.broadcast(searchList.map({ (line) =>
  val Array(a,b) = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
  (a,b.toInt)
  }).collect().toMap)    

val sample1 = sc.textFile("data/data.txt")
val sample2 = sample1.map(line=>(line.split(" ").map(word => sentilex.value.getOrElse(word, 0)).reduce(_ + _), line))
sample2.collect.foreach(println)
 }
}
```

I hope this will be useful

Comment: Thank you @jlopezmat for your reply, i have a question , how can i remove parentheses around every docs, for example one output of above code is : (-2,surprise heard thump opened door small seedy man clasping package wrapped.)

Comment: @Rozita The parentheses appers because you have tuples and its toString method put the parentheses.

If you want to erese them, your code should be:

    `sample2.collect.foreach(tuple => println(tuple._1+","+tuple._2))`

I hope this will be useful

Comment: Dear @jlopezmat , if i want to remove the same words after scoring , how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry @Rozita but i don't understand what do you mean, can you give me an example of what you wanna do?

Comment: for example first line in my data : " -2 ; heard opened door seedy clasping package wrapped. "    after compare two words in two files if these words are same , score added but this word removed.

Comment: @Rozita I still don't fully undestand, but if you want delete the words after evaluation you can change:

    `val sample2 = sample1.map(line=>(line.split(" ").map(word => sentilex.value.getOrElse(word, 0)).reduce(_ + _), line))`

to:

    `val sample2 = sample1.map(line=>(line.split(" ").map(word => sentilex.value.getOrElse(word, 0)).reduce(_ + _), line.filter(word => sentilex.value.contains(word))))`

if you want only one apperance of each word detected in your sentilex's map you have to do something more complex.

Comment: Yes , your solution is ok . but it has an error when running.

Comment: I think: " contains(word)" changed to " not contains(word)"